# Kannel - random smsc

Tags: sms, smpp, kannel

I have Kannel and Goip32.
So, 1 sim-link on Goip is 1 smsc on Kannel.
That's configured as:

```
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = goip101
host = 192.168.1.48
port = 7777
transceiver-mode = true
smsc-username = "goip101"
smsc-password = ""
system-type =
max-pending-submits = 1
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsc-101.log"
log-level = 2

...
2-31
...

group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = goip132
host = 192.168.1.48
port = 7777
transceiver-mode = true
smsc-username = "goip132"
smsc-password = ""
system-type =
max-pending-submits = 1
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsc-132.log"
log-level = 2
```

But kannel sending sms on random smsc, and after sms-delivery on goip101 may be 10 sms, on goip122 - 5 sms, on goip110 - 1 sms (for example).

How can i configured kannel to first chosen goip101, then goip102, then goip103...?

Answer (score 2):

It is the purpose of Kannel to do the load-balancing between your different smsc.

**If you absolutely want to force this order, you can use different smsc-id in your configuration and force the smsc-id when sending.**

Do not forget to add the `allowed-smsc-id` setting for each smsc-id or Kannel will still share the load even if the smsc-id is not specified.

For example, with this configuration:

```
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = idSite1
host = hostname1
port = port1
transceiver-mode = true
smsc-username = username1
smsc-password = password1
max-pending-submits=50

group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = idSite2
host = hostname2
port = port2
transceiver-mode = true
smsc-username = username2
smsc-password = password2
max-pending-submits=50
```

If you specify `smscid=idSite1` while your send, it will still send using idSite1 OR idSite2.

You need to add `allowed-smsc-id = idSite1` at the end of the 1st smsc definition and `allowed-smsc-id = idSite2` at the end of the 2nd one

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the smsc-id in your configuration and for more strictly additonal parameter can be added

```
group = smsc
smsc = smpp

smsc-id = goip101
preferred-smsc-id=goip101
allowed-smsc-id=goip101

host = 192.168.1.48
port = 7777
transceiver-mode = true
smsc-username = "goip101"
smsc-password = ""
system-type =
max-pending-submits = 1
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsc-101.log"
log-level = 2
```